# Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question regarding my following code,
I have a data set and a list , I want to compare each data value of my data set with two conditions, if the condition is true then keep the previous value of the data frame otherwise make it as None, My code works perfectly for small data set however it will takes too much time and without any values for my big data set. Is there better solution?

```
new_data=data
    for col in df.columns:
        for i in range(len(df)):
            if (df.iloc[i][col] >list_min[i] ) & (df.iloc[i][col]<list_max[i]):
                new_data.set_value(i,col,df.iloc[i][col])
            else:
                new_data.set_value(i,col,None)
```

thanks for comments or another solution.

This is my code that is not work :

```
data = pd.read_csv('./dataset/w.csv')
i=0
data = data.applymap(np.log)
data = data.drop('time', axis=1)
q75_list = []
q25_list = []
iqr_list = []
min_list = []
max_list = []
new_data=data
for col in data.columns.values:
    q75_list.append(np.nanpercentile(data[col], 75))
    q25_list.append(np.nanpercentile(data[col], 25))

    iqr_list = np.array(q75_list) - np.array(q25_list)
    min_list = np.array(q25_list) - (np.array(iqr_list * 1.5))
    max_list = np.array(q75_list) + (np.array(iqr_list * 1.5))

print("Max :\n",max_list,"\n Min :\n",min_list)

for col in data.columns:
    for (i, j) in [(i, j) for i in range(len(data)) for j in range(len(min_list))]:

        if (data.iloc[i][col] >min_list[j] ) & (data.iloc[i][col]<max_list[j]):
            new_data.set_value(i,col,data.iloc[i][col])
        else:
            new_data.set_value(i,col,None)

new_data.to_csv('./dataset/result.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: What is *list_min* and *list_max*? It looks to be same length as `df`.

Comment: I used the same length in my small data set. but in other data set I read the length of list_min and list_max.`for col in data.columns:
    for (i, j) in [(i, j) for i in range(len(data)) for j in range(len(min_list))]:`

Comment: Not sure how that answers my question. Where do those objects derive?

Comment: it is hard to understand what your code actually wants to achieve. in general, it will become much faster if you do not manually code all the loops but use vector or matrix operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am correctly understanding what you are doing, there are a couple places you could try to vectorize things. See if this speeds things up:

```
q75s = data.quantile(.75)
q25s = data.quantile(.25)
mins = 2.5*q25s - 1.5*q75s
maxs = 2.5*q75s - 1.5*q25s

newdata = data.copy()
newdata[(data < mins) | (data > maxs)] = None
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the *if/then/else* idiom using [pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html). Below assumes *list_min* and *list_max* are lists of equal length to number of rows in *data*.

```
for col in data.columns:
    new_data.loc[(data[col] > pd.Series(list_min)) & 
                 (data[col] < pd.Series(list_max)), col] = data[col] 

    new_data.loc[(data[col] < pd.Series(list_min)) |
                 (data[col] > pd.Series(list_max)), col] = None
```

To demonstrate with example random data of 10 cols and 50 rows (seeded to reproduce):

**Data**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

np.random.seed(107)
data = pd.DataFrame([[np.random.randint(50) for _ in range(50)] for _ in range(10)]).T
print(data.head())
#     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
# 0  48  17  37  22   1   0   6  14  33  10
# 1  25  38  28   4  36  22   4  24  28  49
# 2   6   5  22  35  14  14  40  41  38  26
# 3  14  43   5  31  38  45  40   5  32   1
# 4  11  30  35  32  20  37  26  39  34   5

list_min = [np.random.randint(50) for _ in range(50)]
print(list_min[:10])
# [37, 17, 33, 24, 0, 46, 11, 4, 25, 41]
list_max = [np.random.randint(50) for _ in range(50)]
print(list_max[:10])
# [45, 37, 49, 38, 31, 9, 20, 39, 7, 36]
```

**Operation**

```
new_data = data.loc[:,]

for col in data.columns:
        new_data.loc[(data[col] > pd.Series(list_min)) & 
                     (data[col] < pd.Series(list_max)), col] = data[col] 

        new_data.loc[(data[col] < pd.Series(list_min)) |
                     (data[col] > pd.Series(list_max)), col] = None

print(new_data.head())
#       0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8    9
# 0   NaN   NaN  37.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
# 1  25.0   NaN  28.0   NaN  36.0  22.0   NaN  24.0  28.0  NaN
# 2   NaN   NaN   NaN  35.0   NaN   NaN  40.0  41.0  38.0  NaN
# 3   NaN   NaN   NaN  31.0  38.0   NaN   NaN   NaN  32.0  NaN
# 4  11.0  30.0   NaN   NaN  20.0   NaN  26.0   NaN   NaN  5.0
```

Comment: Thanks but the length of the lists are not the same as the rows of the data frame, it is the same as the length of the columns.